# Timeline of classic grammarians

Tags: grammarians

I'm seeking a timeline of classic (Greek/Latin) grammarians/grammar books. The timeline could either be a graphical one or a textual listing (like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_English_grammars#Timeline_of_English_grammars) for the English language).

Most favorable is an annotated bibliography with information regarding editions and translations.

I should point to the Wikipedia category pages [Grammarians of Ancient Greek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Grammarians_of_Ancient_Greek) and [Grammarians of Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Grammarians_of_Latin) which are alphabetical and are least favored listings (though they may be used to create a timeline with some effort).

Comment: Eleanor Dickey's *Ancient Greek Scholarship* has a good section on ancient Greek grammarians, and another on lexicographers, with lots of bibliographical information.

Comment: @TKR *Ancient Greek Scholarship* is my desk reference. I also recommend Brill’s *Lexicon of Greek Grammarians of Antiquity*.

Answer (score 3):

You can compose your own from Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Grammarians_of_Latin  but it is as you say **a bit indigestible** even in chronological sequence:

Antonius Rufus (grammarian)
(Dionysius Thrax  Τέχνη γραμματική 150 BC)
Lucius Aelius Stilo Praeconinus Philologist  100BC

Marcus Fabius **Quintilianus** 100AD  Institutio oratoria
Sulpicius Apollinaris 2nd C 
Flavius Caper 2ndC
Eutychius Proclus 2ndC
Aemilius Asper??100 
Antonius Rufus (grammarian) influenced Quintilian

Helenius Acron 3rC
Censorinus 3rd
Arusianus Messius 4th
Tiberius Claudius Donatus 430  Artes Donati,
Rabanus Maurus  abridges Priscian
**Priscian** fl500 sourcesHerodian and Apollonius     inspiredAldhelm, Bede, Alcuin

Signposts and perspectives come with http://www.oxfordbibliographies.com/view/document/obo-9780195389661/obo-9780195389661-0321.xml  For example:

> Donatus and his commentators stole the spotlight for a while (see Servius Honoratus (Marius/Maurus Servius Honoratus; 370/380?–d.?; fl. post-400) and Pompeius Grammaticus (5th/6th Century)), but by the beginning of the 6th century CE, Priscian’s Ars grammatica was regarded as the great achievement of the ancient grammatical tradition. Although it was a Latin grammar, its Greek...

And in greater detail  http://ancientworldonline.blogspot.com/2014/05/fragmentary-latin-grammarians-flg.htm

**TEXTS:**
Wiki footnotes on individual grammarians often evaluate texts.
I rely on the **Internet Archive** (donations); https://archive.org/details/institutioorator03quin/page/n5
and **Thayer** Penelope(University of Chicago) http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/Rhetorica_ad_Herennium/home.html very accurate, e-readable. 
Where on-line texts are not accessible (or scrambled) the University of **Toronto** is worth searching out for good **medieval** sources and advice.
**Loeb** is reasonably priced too https://www.amazon.co.uk/Rhetorica-Herennium-Loeb-Classical.../dp/0674994442

For the very best texts for ambitious Classicists I recommend you ask individual questions, say, on this site: as 'What is the best Ars Grammatica?'

Comment: Thank you @Hugh. What about information about editions and translations? Is there any anthology, reader, etc. (in English translation) of the extant texts?

Comment: @Kaveh You can always start with Brill’s *Lexicon of Greek Grammarians of Antiquity*.

Comment: Thanks @AlexB Is there any similar work for Latin?

Answer (score 1):

To build your library of grammarians here is:
**Alexandre de Villedieu** (born around 1175) Grammar Leonine
(internally rhymed hexameter)
grammar derived from Priscian (Priscianus caesariensis ( fl. AD 500)), and Donatus, Aelius Donatus (fl. mid-fourth century AD)
*not Priscian of Lydia (Priscianus Lydus; fl. 6th century*), one of the last of the Neoplatonists.]

as an example, here is: "***de ceteriis vitiis***" other faults:

> 10. Amphibolia est ambiguitas dictionis, quae fit aut per casum accusativum, ut siquis dicat «audio secutorem retiarium superasse»;
>     aut per commune verbum, ut siquis dicat «criminatur Cato», «vadatur
>     Tullius» nec addat quem vel a quo; aut per distinctionem, ut «vidi
>     statuam auream hastam tenentem». Fit et per homonyma, ut siquis aciem
>     dicat et non  addat oculorum aut exercitus aut ferri. Fit praeterea
>     pluribus modis, quos percensere omnes,    ne nimis longum sit, non
>     oportet. sperare      arrige aures Pamphile